# Название поля в ошибке не соответствует реальному названию поля на странице редактирования

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поле называется - "Полное имя", а в ошибке "Реальное имя".

[В Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/139847416?q=text%3A'Real%20Name%20is%20limited%20to'). Плюс, для случая *few* окончание неверное.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил варианты:

https://ru.traducir.win/string/8335

> В поле «Полное имя» разрешено $numChars$ символа; вы ввели $entered$

https://ru.traducir.win/string/8336

> В поле «Полное имя» разрешено $numChars$ символов; вы ввели $entered$